# MultiPlayer Data best Practice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just want to ask if there is a clean or easy way to save multiple player data in a variable. For example, Player1 data have hp and mana similar to player2. I am new to C# unity. Thanks

I tried to use an array, like int[2] hp and int[2] mana and I think it's not the best way since. I created a Player class with hp and mana and use new but it doesn't work

```
public class PlayerData
{
    public int hp;
    public int mana;
}
```

My goal is like this `PlayerData[0].hp = 100`

Comment: Sorry about that, PlayerData class have the necessary variable or data needed by the player like the hp and mana since it was needed by other players I thought is it ok to put it in a class and reuse it. I picture it out like this `PlayerData[] player = new PlayerData` then `player[0].hp = 100` and` player[1].hp = 90` and i can manipulate it individualy.

Comment: i think you are referring `List<PlayerData>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saving multiple player data in a variable? Yes:**

```
List<PlayerData> playerList = new List<PlayerData>();

for(int i = 0; i < playercount; i++)
{
    PlayerData tempPlayer = new PlayerData();

    tempPlayer.hp = 100;
    tempPlayer.mana = 100;

    playerList.Add(tempPlayer);
}
```

**Getting 2nd Player hp:**

```
playerList[1].hp
```